# Is there a difference in data/promise returned from axios get and post?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm working on a React application that makes use of an imported object with a get request to an api and a post request to a related API.

When creating a new instance of my service in the frontend in React, I am able to successfully use the '.then' & '.catch' functions to access the returned data ONLY from the get request.

When using the post request from the same object, when trying to access the response object, I get a (paraphrased) '.then' is not a function on undefined.

Only when I explicitly write out the post request in my form submit function (without consuming a service) and handling the object there am I able to check the response and subsequently set the state.

What is the appropriate/best practice way for using axios in React and why am I not able to access the response object when I create a new instance of a service?? Much appreciated!

Service:

```
import axios from 'axios';

class ProductServices {
  getAllProducts(){
    return axios.get('https://somecustomAPIURL')
  }

  postProduct(somePathConfig){
    axios.request({
      url: 'https://somecustomAPIURL' + somePathConfig,
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'some-custom-header': process.env.REACT_APP_API_POST_KEY}
    })
  }

}

export default ProductServices;
```

```
React Code instantiating and consuming the service (note, that getAllProducts works just fine, but trying to consume a response object in postProduct returns an '.then' is undefined)


  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      products: [],
      productID: null,
      showModal: false
    }
    this.ProductServices = new ProductServices();
  }

  getAllProducts = () => {
    this.ProductServices.getAllProducts()
    .then((response) => {
      let items = response.data.data.items;
      this.setState({
        products: items,
        productID: items[0].id
      });
      return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error!', error);
      return error;
    })
  }

  handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let productID = this.state.productID;
this.ProductServices.postProduct(productID)
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({showModal: true}, () => console.log('Success!'));
      return response;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error!', err);
    })
  }
```

Comment: You're missing the `return` in front of `axios.request`.

Comment: Thanks, @EmileBergeron! I feel like I tried different permutations of return statements (the code posted in my latest iteration/implementation) and for whatever, reason, that seems to have done the trick.

This is an example of closure, correct?

Comment: Happy it worked! It will likely be closed as the problem can no longer be reproduced since it's caused by a "typo", which is not useful for future readers most of the time. You can definitely close the question yourself to avoid the hassle of the review process before the official closure.

Comment: Right will do :). I meant is this an example of 'closure' the programming tool (exposing some underlying piece of code after the containing function has returned already).

And I've upvoted your answer, but I'm not seeing any checkmark to at least give you your props before I close this :).

Comment: Ohh right haha! It's a common mistake with the async nature of JS and the different syntaxes that can be used to do similar things, like arrow functions, method short-hand, function expressions, etc.

Comment: @jb07 The only thing closure-related is that there *is* one, but you're not creating a function that returns later. It's simply that the function doesn't return anything that implements a `then` function.

Answer (score 3):

You missed `return` before `axios.request`.

```
import axios from 'axios';

class ProductServices {
...
  postProduct(somePathConfig){
    return axios.request({
      url: 'https://somecustomAPIURL' + somePathConfig,
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'some-custom-header': process.env.REACT_APP_API_POST_KEY}
    })
  }
...
```

Also, instead of `axios.request`, you can use `axios.post` like `axios.get`

```
return axios.post(url, body, { headers });
return axios.get(url, { headers });
return axios.put(url, body, { headers });
return axios.delete(url, { headers });
return axios.request(axiosConfigOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks @Allen Haley --

In this case, I went with axios.request because of my now resolved issue and because I am not passing any data on this particular post request, just submitting a product id to augment the url path. Would it still be advisable to use axios.post with data/body??

Comment: @jb07 in your use-case, `.request` is fine ;)

Comment: @EmileBergeron to save the day once again :). I'm grateful

Comment: @jb07, you can use `axios.post(url, {}, {headers});`. But it's your choice. :)

Comment: Thanks for the insight @AllenHaley :)